SSH into Virtual machine issues
I recently set up an Ubuntu server inside a virtual machine and I have been trying to SSH into this VM from the host (using Oracle VirtualBox). I keep receiving a timeout error no matter what I try.
I have added exceptions to the firewall ufw for tcp port 22 and allow echo replies via ufw, I have gone over the network adapter settings in virtual box and have the network adapter bridged.
Ran the following command to accept echo requests as well "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT"
